# bashrc that calls other bashrc depending on linux distro

Tags: bash, bashrc

I login to a system that reads my bashrc file and loads some software ready to use.

I'd like to load a given bashrc file depending on the linux system that I am logging into.

Specifically, if I am logging into a system with centOS 6, I'd like to load my centos6 bashrc:

```
cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

and if I am logging into a system with centOS 5.7, I'd like to load my centOS 5.7 bashrc.

```
cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
```

I am thinking along the lines of having 3 bashrc files  in my home dir:

.bashrc
with an if condition such that if finds that I was logging in into centOS6 would run,

```
source ~/.bashrc.centos6
```

and an else, such that if finds that I was logging in into centOS5.7 would run,

```
source ~/.bashrc.centos5
```

So I guess my .bashrc code would look kind of like this:

```
if cat /etc/*-release == "CentOs release 6.4"
   source ~/.bashrc.centos6
elif cat /etc/*-release == "CentOs release 5.7"
   source ~/.bashrc.centos5
```

I am still new to bash scripting so I have no idea how I'd do that and if its a god way to go to achieve my goal.

Comment: Learn more about `grep` as well as shell command return values and the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `lsb_release` command (*should* be in most distros by default):

```
shopt -s nocasematch

if [ -x "$(which lsb_release)" ]; then
  case "$(lsb_release -si)" in
    *centos*)
      case "$(lsb_release -sr)" in
        5.7*)
          source ~/.bashrc.centos5.7
          ;;
        5*)
          # source something for any other version 5 minor release
          ;;
        6*)
          source ~/.bashrc.centos6
          ;;
      esac
    ;;
  esac
fi

shopt -u nocasematch
```

Depending on the exact output of `lsb_release -si` and `lsb_release -sr`. You can add more cases as needed.

Comment: More portable than `/etc/*release`?

Comment: @mikeserv, maybe if you used `/etc/*release /etc/*[-_]version`, this would be more portable.

Comment: I dunno, but if I do `lsb_release` I get "n\a" whereas `cat /etc/*release` gives me a whole slew of information - this guy just taught me that by the way. And you just taught me about lsb_release.

Comment: @mikeserv `lsb_release` on its own doesn't give anything. You need `lsb_release -a` to get all the information or use the different arguments to get specific fields as above.

Comment: @mikeserv, http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/os-release.html. There is a footnote at the bottom with some of the different files used.

Comment: -a is better, though I'm pretty sure what I'm getting are the values set in /etc/*release - it appears that way, anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv, I just worry that `/etc/*release` might match something its not supposed to. `/etc/*version` matches `/etc/subversion`.

Comment: Could be - I have no idea. I think the question was more about how to robustly handle conditionals though. I was curious - and -a does give me info, so I was wrong. I'd just never heard of it.

Comment: @Graeme seems exactly like what I need, but when I tried it out, I got an error: -bash: .bashrc: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `;;' not sure why

Comment: @Dnaiel, oops, missed an `esac`. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @Dnaiel, there is no need to change the case - I used `shopt -s nocaseglob` specifically so that the match would be case insensitive.

Comment: @Graeme, thanks a lot, for some reason it did not work in my linux system without that change, quite odd.

Comment: @Dnaiel, my bad, it should have been `nocasematch` instead of `nocaseglob`. Updated.

Comment: @Graeme, thanks! great, I'll try that then.

Comment: @Graeme it was working perfectly fine until I tried doing ftp connection... if i try with this bashrc it'd not open the ftp connection... quite odd!

Comment: @Graeme, if I do scp <myowncomuter> <server> it does not scp the files and get stuck... v strange...

Comment: @Dnaiel, I don't see any way that the above can affect your `scp` or `ftp`. It could be something to do with the contents of the files you are sourcing. If you can't work it out please ask another question detailing exactly what you have done and the errors you are getting and hopefully someone can help.

Comment: @Graeme I am almost sure it must be the bashrc since if I change it back to one of the given bashrc's it works, but great suggestion anyways.  I'll look more into it and otherwise ask another related question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use-case for `${parameter+substitution}` since we're talking about parameters after all.

```
  _src_release() {
     . ${RELEASE:=/path/to/fallback}
      } <<GET_RELEASE
         ${PREFERRED="$(whatever gets you /path/to/preferred)"}
         ${NEXT_BEST="$(something else gets you /path/to/next/best)"}
         ${IF_YOU_MUST="$(get /the/third/option)"}
         ${RELEASE="${PREFERRED:-"${NEXT_BEST:-"${IF_YOU_MUST}"}"}"}
     GET_RELEASE
```

You could also do all of the logic in a for loop in command substitution then just echo the results out into `$RELEASE` when you get it. The point of this is that the variable can test its own value if you use it correctly.

So when you `.dot` source `$RELEASE` if none of those variables set in its input have been populated with other than `NULL` values it will just `. /path/to/fallback.`

You can do as many of those as you like in that fashion, but also a `|| short-circuit` test just following the shell's `.dot` statement above will handle its errors - this is really easy to use - and you can it look and mean like what it does, which can be helpful.

That's if you wanna do it in `.profile,` but I suspect the best way is in `/etc/login.defs` with `$ENV_PATH` or `/etc/passwd.` For each distro that you want to login to you could either create a special link that will only `$PATH` for that specific distro or specifically set the shell executable to be a wrapper script for what you want. That way it is actually is handled by the login daemon and not by subvertible profile scripts.